# Cloudflare "Cache Everything" causing errors

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I own a gaming related website and we appear to be experiencing some errors with both our login system and interactive chat platform that is integrated with the site.

We recently integrated cloudflare and have setup the caching to "cache everything" and im wondering if this is what is causing the errors we are experiencing, if that is the case how do I go about adding further page rules that prevent certain area being cached? Is this is a common problem?

Comment: give some tried code snipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for us to know if caching is causing the problem with the information you've given.

You can test it yourself though by going into the `Caching` tab in CloudFlare and purge everything or do a custom purge of single items to see if the problem goes away.